# Detect Slow Queries In SQLAlchemy And Kill Them

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Separate from connection timeouts, there are also results timeouts, where a timeout is given if a query takes longer than `n` number of seconds to **completely** return. This should result in an exception being thrown so I can give error page to the user. You may have seen this behavior on Github and Reddit under heavy loads. These sites auto kill the page and return a "This page took to long to render" error in order to relieve some pressure on their databases.

Very few ORMs have this functionality, and it seems SQLAlchemy also doesn't have it. Is there any way to manually do this with SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Your database backend should provide this capability. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @univerio MySQL on Amazon RDS

Comment: Look at [`max_execution_time`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_execution_time). There are some caveats that apply though.